# Ошибка при отправке по FTP

Tags: delphi

Пытаюсь передать файлик по фтп исполькуя такой код:

```
 ftp:=TIdFTP.Create(Application);          //отправляем файл по FTP
  ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 try
try
  ftp.Host:=host;// ftp адрес сервера
  ftp.Port:=21;
  ftp.Username:=login;//логин
  ftp.Password:=pass;//Пароль
  ftp.Connect(true, 2000);  ругается на эту строку (тип ошибки ниже)
  AssErt(ftp.Connected);
  ftp.ChangeDir('/');//Установить папку на сервере
  ftp.Put('fresh-proxy.html','fresh-proxy.html',false); //Файл Откуда-Куда
  ShowMessage('Send HTML file');
finally
  ms.Free; ftp.Free;
end;
except
ShowMessage('Error');
 end;
```

вот такую ошибку выдаёт:
    [DCC Error] Project1.dpr(207): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Connect' that can be called with these arguments

Answer (score 1):

Компилятор ругается на то, что вы, либо передаете неверное количество аргументов в метод **Connect**, либо их тип неправильный.

**UPDATED:** попробуйте вызвать **Connect(nil)**.

Comment: блин ну это я и так понял, прикол в том что в мануалах именно так

Comment: Вызывайте Connect без параметров.

Comment: @Никола , ну или попробуйте установить эти же переменные как-то по другому. Например, при инициализации объекта. Обновил ответ.